# auto increment android versionCode and VersionName using perl

Tags: android, perl

I have an android manifest.xml  file with android versionCode:12 and versionName:1.0.1.2 and I am trying to autoincrement the versionCode and VersionName using perl with major,minor,patch and build logic using perl script. Here is my manifest file. After auto increment versionName will be like as 1.0.1.3 and versionCode as 13.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.0.1.2" package="com.test.prat" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Also I have strings.xml file to update versionName in strings.xml file the auto increment versionName should be updated as well in strings.xml file. Here is my strings.xml file

```
<!-- This file is automatically generated, please do not update -->

<!-- decibel abbreviation -->
<string name="txt_abbreviation_decibel_label">dB</string> 
<string name="txt_android_app_version">1.0.1.2</string>
</resources>
```

After that auto increment I want to set the versionName as environment variable to use the during svn commit phase for example ‘svn commit “update versionName  1.0.1.2”’

Please advise.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(1.0.1.2)|versionCode="\K(12)/($1)?"1.0.1.3":13/eg; ' xml.txt`

Comment: Looks to me this is hard code i want to auto increment both versionCode and versionName. and set the versionName as environment variable. Please can you have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `Version::Next` module in your machine after installing you can try the following one liner

```
perl -MVersion::Next=next_version -pe's/(1\.0\.1\.2)|versionCode="\K(12)/
    $1 ? next_version($1) : next_version($2) /eg' file.xml
```

Comment: I tired, but no luck, when ever i run the script versionCode  and versionName should be incremented automatically, for example if i run once it is incremented to 1.0.1.3, again if i run the perl script it will be incremented by 1.0.1.4 automatically. Please is there any best way to write Perl script.

Comment: @krishna you will have to do a little bit of work yourself. This answer gives you the ground work, but the initial version is hard coded. We answer questions here, not do your work for you. If you want it to work with dynamic versions, change it.

Comment: Ok thanks, But i totally new this to perl. Want to change it dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: Using `next_version` is silly when the parameter can only ever be one value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which XML parser you are using, so I'm going to assume XML::LibXML.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use Version::Next qw( next_version );
use XML::LibXML   qw( );

use constant ANDROID_NS => 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android';

my $qfn = $ARGV[0];

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $qfn );
my $manifest_node = $doc->documentElement();

for my $version_node (
   $manifest_node->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionName'),
   $manifest_node->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionCode'),
) {
   my $version = $version_node->getValue();
   $version = next_version($version);
   $version_node->setValue($version);
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am  using manifest.xml file to increment the versionCode and versionName. I think i need to read the manifest file am i right? ' .

Comment: ' '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.0.1.2" package="com.test.prat" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission '

Comment: What? . . . . .

Comment: I mean,  from your script how can i read the manifest.xml file, i mean how i can parse my xml file

Comment: sorry to ask you again, I am confusing for example in other language i can parse the xml file 'dom1 = parse("AndroidManifest.xml")'  in your code how it will read and fetch the versionCode and versionName  the the manifest.xml file.

Comment: Same idea with XML::LibXML.

Comment: when i run the script, it is giving error but i downloaded version::next module though it is giving error 'Can't locate Version/Next.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Version::Next module) (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at versionperl.pl line 7.'

Comment: I installed please ignore my latest comment

Comment: when i run the script  it is giving error. 'Can't locate object method "getAttributeNodeNS" via package "50275552" (perhaps you forgot to load "50275552"?) at versionperl.pl line 10' . here is my code'

Comment: code --  'use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $filename = 'AndroidManifest.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);
use Version::Next qw( next_version );
use constant ANDROID_NS => 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android';
#my $manifest_node = $doc->documentElement();
for my $version_node (
   $$dom->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionName'),
   $dom->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionCode'),
) {
   my $version = $version_node->getValue();
   $version = next_version($version);
   $version_node->setValue($version);
}'

Comment: please can you advise

Comment: `$$dom` should be `$dom->documentElement()`. And `$dom` is a ::Document node, so `$doc` makes more sense as a name.

Comment: I ran the below script but it is compiled but versionCode and versionName is not updated in manifest.xml file.

Comment: I am trying to put the code but not allowing can you please help on this

Comment: @krishna, Did you save your changes?

Comment: ,yes, I saved my changes.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I have no idea what you did wrong. And that's why you shouldn't be asking new questions in the comments. I have updated my answer to have complete working code.

Comment: I edited my code in above.  it is not updating versionCode and versionName in manifest file.

Comment: I can't tell you why code I've never seen doesn't work.

Comment: use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use Version::Next qw( next_version );
use XML::LibXML   qw( );
use constant ANDROID_NS => 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android';
my $qfn = $ARGV[0];
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $qfn );
my $manifest_node = $doc->documentElement();
for my $version_node (
$manifest_node->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionName'),
$manifest_node->getAttributeNodeNS(ANDROID_NS, 'versionCode'),
) {
my $version = $version_node->getValue();
$version = next_version($version);
$version_node->setValue($version);
}
$doc->toFile($qfn);